# Can I load a UIImage from a URL?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a URL for an image (got it from UIImagePickerController) but I no longer have the image in memory (the URL was saved from a previous run of the app).  Can I reload the UIImage from the URL again?

I see that UIImage has a imageWithContentsOfFile: but I have a URL.  Can I use NSData's dataWithContentsOfURL: to read the URL?

### EDIT1

---

based on @Daniel's answer I tried the following code but it doesn't work...

```
NSLog(@"%s %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, photoURL);     
if (photoURL) {
    NSURL* aURL = [NSURL URLWithString:photoURL];
    NSData* data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:aURL];
    self.photoImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    [data release];
}
```

When I ran it the console shows:

```
-[PhotoBox willMoveToWindow:] file://localhost/Users/gary/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/3.2/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0004.JPG
*** -[NSURL length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x536fbe0
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x536fbe0'
```

Looking at the call stack, I'm calling URLWithString, which calls URLWithString:relativeToURL:, then initWithString:relativeToURL:, then _CFStringIsLegalURLString, then CFStringGetLength, then **forwarding_prep_0**, then **forwarding**, then -[NSObject doesNotRecognizeSelector].

Any ideas why my NSString (photoURL's address is 0x536fbe0) doesn't respond to length?  Why does it say it doesn't respond to -[NSURL length]?  Doesn't it know that param is an NSString, not a NSURL?

### EDIT2

---

OK, the only problem with the code is the string to URL conversion.  If I hardcode the string, everything else works fine.  So something is wrong with my NSString and if I can't figure it out, I guess that should go in as a different question.  With this line inserted (I pasted the path from the console log above), it works fine:

```
photoURL = @"file://localhost/Users/gary/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/3.2/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0004.JPG";
```

Comment: It seems like photoURL is already an NSURL, not an NSString, given that NSLog handled it.

Comment: @drawn: Looks like an error in the docs.  It says that UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL is an NSString but it's actually an NSURL object.

Comment: The library DLImageLoader is INCREDIBLE.  rock solid, no doco, one command and everything is perfect.  What a find.

Comment: I second (third?) DLImageLoader. I was skeptical about whether the comments about it on this page were objective - but I tried it anyway and it does work very nicely.

I have a UIImageView within a UITableViewCell. All I did was replace the UIImageView with a DLImageView, then called the imageFromUrl: method to load the image, and it all just works -- asynchronous loading, caching, etc. Couldn't be easier.

Comment: DLImageLoader remains fantastic, another good one is **Haneke**, although it suffers a little from being not quite maintained.

Comment: All these replies are really not answering your question, you only need to deal with a local path, no need for all these complex async methods, see my answer below.

Answer (score 328, accepted):

You can do it this way (synchronously, but compact):

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:MyURL]]];
```

A much better approach is to use Apple's LazyTableImages to preserve interactivity.

Comment: Doesn't the data need to be converted from PNG (or JPG) file format to UIImage data?  Or does UIImage figure that out somehow?

Comment: Guess I should just RTFM, it says right in UIImage Class Reference what file formats it can support and imageWithData: says it can be data from a file, sounds like it should work.

Comment: @Daniel: didn't work, I edited my question to include my actual code and the exception info.  It's a little bizarre.

Comment: @Daniel: it does work if I use a string constant instead of the NSString I was passing in.  So this latest problem was something wrong with my NSString, not a problem with the NSURL/NSData/UIImage code which works.  Thanks Daniel!

Comment: If you're using just one image and you're looking for a quick fix you can just write a bit of code that caches the single image.

Comment: Using this answer in conjunction with the answer here worked very well for me! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16283652/understanding-dispatch-async

Comment: This is one of the worse answer.

Answer (score 27):

You can try [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage), it provides:

1. Asynchronous loading
2. Caching for offline use
3. Place holder image to appear while loading
4. Works well with UITableView

Quick example:

```
    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

Comment: I have modified that library a bit and integrated it with UIImage+Resize in order to add Resize/Crop capabilities to it. If you need that check it out at https://github.com/toptierlabs/ImageCacheResize

Comment: This example populates a `UIImageView`. `SDWebImage` also lets you populate a `UIImage` directly using `SDWebImageManager` `- (void) downloadWithURL:...`.  See their example on the read me.

Answer (score 13):

And the swift version :

```
   let url = NSURL.URLWithString("http://live-wallpaper.net/iphone/img/app/i/p/iphone-4s-wallpapers-mobile-backgrounds-dark_2466f886de3472ef1fa968033f1da3e1_raw_1087fae1932cec8837695934b7eb1250_raw.jpg");
    var err: NSError?
    var imageData :NSData = NSData.dataWithContentsOfURL(url,options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: &err)
    var bgImage = UIImage(data:imageData)
```

Answer (score 7):

get [DLImageLoader](https://github.com/AndreyLunevich/DLImageLoader-iOS/tree/master/DLImageLoader) and try folowing code

```
   [DLImageLoader loadImageFromURL:imageURL
                          completed:^(NSError *error, NSData *imgData) {
                              imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
                              [imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeCenter];

                          }];
```

---

Another typical real-world example of using DLImageLoader, which may help someone...

```
PFObject *aFacebookUser = [self.fbFriends objectAtIndex:thisRow];
NSString *facebookImageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
    @"http://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large",
    [aFacebookUser objectForKey:@"id"] ];

__weak UIImageView *loadMe = self.userSmallAvatarImage;
// ~~note~~ you my, but usually DO NOT, want a weak ref
[DLImageLoader loadImageFromURL:facebookImageURL
   completed:^(NSError *error, NSData *imgData)
    {
    if ( loadMe == nil ) return;

    if (error == nil)
        {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
        image = [image ourImageScaler];
        loadMe.image = image;
        }
    else
        {
        // an error when loading the image from the net
        }
    }];
```

As I mention above another great library to consider these days is **Haneke** (unfortunately it's not as lightweight).

Comment: SDWebImage is the most popular library in Objective-C and KingFisher is the Swift port.

Comment: True , but DLImageLoader is better!  :)

Answer (score 7):

If you're *really*, absolutely **positively** sure that the NSURL is a file url, i.e. `[url isFileURL]` is guaranteed to return true in your case, then you can simply use:

```
[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:url.path]
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this code, you can set loading image with it, so the users knows that your app is loading an image from url:

```
UIImageView *yourImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"loading.png"]];
    [yourImageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];

    //Request image data from the URL:
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yourdomain.com/yourimg.png"]];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (imgData)
            {
                //Load the data into an UIImage:
                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];

                //Check if your image loaded successfully:
                if (image)
                {
                    yourImageView.image = image;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Failed to load the data into an UIImage:
                    yourImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"no-data-image.png"];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //Failed to get the image data:
                yourImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"no-data-image.png"];
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: I preferred this solution since it didn't require loading any 3rd party frameworks or instantiating data loading queues, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the `AsyncImageView` provided over [here](http://www.markj.net/iphone-asynchronous-table-image/).  Some good example code, and might even be usable right "out of the box" for you.

Comment: Interesting example, it's very similar in concept to Apple's LazyTableImages example mentioned in the earlier answer.

Comment: It's similar but beware that AsyncImageView really doesn't work in tables, at least not when you recycle table cells (as you should).

Answer (score 4):

[AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) provides async image loading into a UIImageView with placeholder support. It also supports async networking for working with APIs in general.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure enable this settings from iOS 9:

**App Transport Security Settings** in **Info.plist** to ensure loading image from URL so that it will allow download image and set it.

[image]

And write this code:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://feelgrafix.com/data/images/images-1.jpg"];
NSData *data =[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
quickViewImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

Answer (score 2):

The way using a Swift [Extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html) to `UIImageView` (source code [here](https://gist.github.com/fpg1503/831a395cf4f4e3dddb1e)):

### Creating Computed Property for Associated `UIActivityIndicatorView`

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import ObjectiveC

private var activityIndicatorAssociationKey: UInt8 = 0

extension UIImageView {
    //Associated Object as Computed Property
    var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView! {
        get {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &activityIndicatorAssociationKey) as? UIActivityIndicatorView
        }
        set(newValue) {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &activityIndicatorAssociationKey, newValue, UInt(OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN))
        }
    }

    private func ensureActivityIndicatorIsAnimating() {
        if (self.activityIndicator == nil) {
            self.activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray)
            self.activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
            let size = self.frame.size;
            self.activityIndicator.center = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height/2);
            NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({ () -> Void in
                self.addSubview(self.activityIndicator)
                self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
            })
        }
    }
```

### Custom Initializer and Setter

```
    convenience init(URL: NSURL, errorImage: UIImage? = nil) {
        self.init()
        self.setImageFromURL(URL)
    }

    func setImageFromURL(URL: NSURL, errorImage: UIImage? = nil) {
        self.ensureActivityIndicatorIsAnimating()
        let downloadTask = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(URL) {(data, response, error) in
            if (error == nil) {
                NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({ () -> Void in
                    self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                    self.image = UIImage(data: data)
                })
            }
            else {
                self.image = errorImage
            }
        }
        downloadTask.resume()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Best and easy way to load Image via Url is by this Code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSData *data =[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgUrl]];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        imgView.image= [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    });
});
```

Replace `imgUrl` by your `ImageURL`
Replace `imgView` by your `UIImageView`.

It will load the Image in another Thread, so It will not slow down your App load.

Answer (score 0):

Local URL's are super simple, just use this :

```
UIImage(contentsOfFile: url.path)
```