# Deadlock when calling dispatch_sync() even though it's on another queue

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch, deadlock

I am aware that calling dispatch_async in the current queue will cause a deadlock, however, experiencing a deadlock in a completely different queue:

```
-(void) deadlock{
    // we reach this point in the main queue
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_queue_create("lucas", 0), ^{
        NSLog(@"Doing something in the bakcgound...");
        // We reach this point in another queue, but it deadlocks!
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"Will I ever get here?????");
        });
    });
}
```

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong??

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's a deadlock. Just like you have been creating an example of one

```
-(void) deadlock{

    // we reach this point in the main queue
    //and so main queue waits till this task will finish
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_queue_create("lucas", 0), ^{

        //doing something in background
        //while main queue still blocked by that dispatch_sync() call
        NSLog(@"Doing something in the bakcgound...");

        // We reach this point in another queue, but it deadlocks!
        //Of cause it does!!! Main queue is still waiting till task dispatched to "lucas" queue synchronously finishes. But it can't - waits for main queue to perform this later bock synchronously
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             NSLog(@"Will I ever get here?????");
        });
    }); 
 }
 //we reach this point only after all code written above will performed. so, in our case, this point is unreachable either way
```

So, dependently on your task, you should change one of this dispatch_sync() to dispatch_async().

Answer (score 1):

`Dispatch_sync` is semantically equivalent to a traditional mutex lock, rather than creating a thread. Try the following, will give you: "Is main thread: 1".

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_queue_create("lucas", 0), ^{

    NSLog(@"Doing something in the bakcgound...");
    NSLog(@"Is main thread: %d", [NSThread isMainThread]);

    // We reach this point in another queue, but it deadlocks!
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"Will I ever get here?????");
    });
});
```

What you want I think is more or less the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16283719/1035008):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){

    NSLog(@"Doing something in the bakcgound...");

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
         NSLog(@"Will I ever get here?????");
    });
});
```

Comment: So even though I call dispatch_queue_create("lucas", 0) it doesn't create a new queue??!!  This is weird.

Comment: It does. But that doesn't mean that this queue won't run on a main NSThread. When one creates a queue, he is not provided with any info about a thread, on which tasks from that queue will run

Comment: @cfisher, I think you confuse the queue and the thread here. You can use `dispatch_async` (see my edits for more detail) to create a thread, or use [NSObject to spawn a thread](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH15-SW13).