# Ambiguous use of 'dispatch_get_main_queue()'

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, ambiguous, dispatch-queue

How do I replace the following Swift code for iOS using the `DispatchQueue` class? This is old Swift 3 code that the newest Xcode won't convert to Swift 5.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
  // code
}
```

It is giving me an error that says

> Ambiguous use of 'dispatch_get_main_queue()'

for `dispatch_get_main_queue()`.

The following answer seems to be the right answer, and I want to use it, but could someone tell me this is correct? [Swift version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38268602/6657172)

It says to use the following code:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {

    // Background Thread

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // Run UI Updates
    }
}
```

Other than using `DispatchQueue`, what other alternative do I have to fix this error?

Comment: Not that it’s terribly relevant, but this `dispatch_sync` code is likely older than that, predating Swift 3, in which this new `DispatchQueue` syntax was introduced. See WWDC 2016’s [Concurrent Programming With GCD in Swift 3](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/720/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. That's the new updated syntax.