# Cache table of images

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, caching

I am wanting to be able to view my app offline and all the images in my table. Currently all my images get cached. But not the actual table of results.

```
NSMutableArray *images;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xxxxxxx.co.uk/jsonimages.php"];
        NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        NSError *error = nil;

        if (jsonData) {

            NSDictionary *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData
                                                                   options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
            images = result[@"images"];
        }
}
```

So that gives me a list of image urls, which I then have on my table like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

    SimpleTableCell *cell = (SimpleTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

[cell.thumbnailImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:encodedString]
                            placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
}
```

Which caches `encodedString` using SDWebimage

But if I go onto the app without any access to the internet no images appear. Is this because I need to cache the array?

Comment: Simply use the **AMAZING** DLImageLoader.  Full code examples .. http://stackoverflow.com/a/19115912/294884

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't see the images when lunching your app without internet because your are using a memory cache. You should use a disk cache if you want your images still there when you quit your application. You can configure the `SDWebimage` library to handle this for you.

From the `SDWebimage` documentation :

> It is also possible to use the aync based image cache store
>   independently. SDImageCache maintains a memory cache and an optional
>   disk cache. Disk cache write operations are performed asynchronous so
>   it doesn't add unnecessary latency to the UI.

[Complete documentattion](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

Edit :
You can do something like this (code not tested) :

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

    SimpleTableCell *cell = (SimpleTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    SDImageCache *imageCache = [SDImageCache sharedImageCache];
    [imageCache queryDiskCacheForKey:encodedString done:^(UIImage *image, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {

 if (image){
             cell.thumbnailImageView.image = image;
         }else{
 [cell.thumbnailImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:encodedString] completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {
            [imageCache storeImage:image forKey:encodedString];

        }];  
}


    }];

return cell;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for sharing this. How would I implement this with my code? I don't quite understand the documentation is [this](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage#using-asynchronous-image-caching-independently) the one I should be looking at?

Comment: What is the `image` ?

Comment: I am getting this error: `Incompatible block pointer types sending 'void (^)(UIImage *__strong)' to parameter of type 'SDWebImageQueryCompletedBlock' (aka 'void (^)(UIImage *__strong, SDImageCacheType)')`

Comment: ah yes. The maintainer of the SDWebImage does'nt update the documentation to include the new method queryDiskCacheForKey:...i have updated my answer.

Comment: It is not downloading the images at all now!

Comment: I have put my iphone on flight mode after 'opening' all the images and they still don't appear

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54352/discussion-between-maximilian-and-samir).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using core data to store the information which drives your table view, you could also download the images to the documents directory and store a reference to their location on disk in core data, take a look [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started) and [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/15916/how-to-synchronize-core-data-with-a-web-service-part-1) for some great tutorials by Ray Wenderlich