# parse.com need image from other table

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, relationship

This is just a part of my app but I am always getting stuck on the same problem, it goes something like this:

I have 2 tables on parse: Posts and Companies

Post has these fields

```
objectId
subject
companyId (object id of Company)
```

Company has these fields

```
objectId
companyLogo
```

I made 2 custom classes

```
**Post**
@property (nonatomic) UIImage *companyImage;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *objectId;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *subject;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *companyId;



**Company**
@property (nonatomic) PFile *companyLogo;
@property (nonatomic) UIImage *companyImage;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *objectId;
```

In a singleton class I made 2 MutableArrays that are filled with those 2 custom classes.

The problem I have now is how do I efficiently get the companyLogo from Company and put it in the Post image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the problem - you're usually wrong to keep the OBJECTID of the company, in Post.

You should simply keep an object there .. the column in Post can actually be a pointer to an "Company".

Here's two examples...

[image]

Notice this "Post" table literally has a USER as a column, i called it "author:".

[image]

Here a "Comment" table has an "author" column which is literally a "User" and the "regardingPost" is again a pointer column, it's literally a Post.

(Note that in the Parse dash, it shows the ID, of, the object you are pointing to - very handy.)

This is a basic of using Parse. In the first instance, you need to **go back and rework your tables** so that you have, in your example, your table "Post" simply contains a pointer to company.

*{Footnote - in some obscure cases, in Parse, you do need to keep the 'actual' objectID rather than the item itself, the pointer. That is not relevant here.}*

So, first fix that. Now you ask, how to easily get that "company image" when you get a Post.

This is one of the central amazing things about Parse - it's incredibly easy. It's what the "include" concept comes in.  Your query would look something like this...

```
PFQuery *QQ = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Posts"];
[QQ whereKey:@"subject" equalTo:"Farming"];
QQ.limit = 1000;
[QQ includeKey:@"author"];
QQ.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
[QQ orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
```

notice the "includeKey".

Then, let's say you have your "Posts".  You're going through a loop and each post is "onePost".

So of course you can do this...

```
topic = [aPost objectForKey:@"topic"];
city = [aPost objectForKey:@"cityCode"];
state = [aPost objectForKey:@"state"];
```

and so on.  to get the whole company object, you **simply do this...**

```
PFObject *thatCompany = [aPost objectForKey:@"company"];
```

and that's why we all use Parse!

then of course you can get anything from thatCompany, like the image

```
yourImage = [thatCompany objectForKey:@"companyImage"];
```

Don't forget to do this, you would have **converted your table to use an actual pointer column** as I explain above.

Note that pointer columns (which are what you "always do" in parse, they are ubiquitous -- most of your columns will be pointer columns) are well explained simply on Parse.com, click to documentation and on the left click iOS.

I hope this helps because it took a long time to write :)  Cheers

---

Just FYI this may help you.  Here's the correct way to load images in to a UIImageView.

```
@implementation UIImageView (Hexaface)

-(void)loadAvatarImage:(PFUser *)whom
// literally, for this UIImageView, set the user avatar image
  {
  if ( whom == nil ) return;
  
  PFFile *parseImageFile = [whom objectForKey:@"yourImageColumn"];
  
  __weak UIImageView *mySelf = self;
  if ( parseImageFile != nil )
    {
    [parseImageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *result, NSError *error)
      {
      if ( error != nil ) { return; }
      UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:result];
      
      mySelf.image = image;
      }];
    }
  else
    {
    NSLog(@"catastrophe, loadAvatarImage found no image ...............");
    }
  }
```

If you are a beginner programmer and you are not using categories, either (a) just adopt the code and make it a normal call in your class.  Or, I strongly recommend this is the perfect opportunity to learn about categories.  Remember that in iOS you use categories constantly, always (much if nor most of your code will be categories).

---

**Note** I will tip you an incredibly useful tip for working with iOS and Parse.  There is an amazingly useful library called...

## DLImageLoader

which you more or less have to use when working with images in iOS particularly with Parse. DLImageLoader is your solution.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19115912/294884

full working example there.  the library is completely free, grab the two files and use it. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer. I never used categories before..i will look into that its for adding methods to a class right. I added a pointer to the Company class and called it company...i filled it with the object ID when i click on it, it shows the company... so far so good. in xcode i added     [query includeKey:@"company"];
It automaticly sees it as my custom class when logging it. Amazing how did i not know about this :)!!!  just a question... i also use the company class in other views... am i downloading the images again or does it automaticly know its the same image ?

Comment: i am implementing the library now :) its like a new world is opening for me and i am changing my whole database and all models because of your tips :) i just posted a new parse.com question regarding your tip: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24106562/pfuser-with-pointer-not-getting-data-back