# UIimage may not respond to "setImageWithUrl" iOS

Tags: ios, uiimage, cell

I want to display an image using a URL in an image view. I tried using this:

```
[cell.avatarImageView.image setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.innovaworks.com/wp-content/themes/innovaworks/images/home_person.png"]];
```

but it gives me this warning :

> UIImage may not respond to "setImageWithUrl"

and the image not shown.

Comment: are you using custum cell?

Comment: The error is quite self explanatory. `UIImage` doesn't have a `setImageWithURL:` method. If one of your categories define that method, then you need to add to your question. Your app would normally crash from an error like this but I'm assuming that the image of the image property is `nil` which is why nothing happens at runtime.

Comment: Yess i use custom cell

Comment: Custom cell or not, UIImage still doesn't have such a method

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist : I do not understand why i found a yellow warning before compiling UIImage may not respond to "setImageWithUrl". When i execute, application don't crash but the image not shown

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist: how can i resolve the problem that you say, im a beginner

Comment: @arbi mahdi.. remove ".image" from your code.. it will work.. else your code is correct.. this is coz UIImage doesn't have a setImageWithURL:method. :)

Comment: @ arbi mahndi .. most welcome.. please accept my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no method on UIImage to set the image with a url.

See this answer for a full description of how to set an image from the data contents of a url:https://stackoverflow.com/a/2782491/209867

The gist is:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.innovaworks.com/wp-content/themes/innovaworks/images/home_person.png"]]];
```

Understand that this is **synchronous**  The scroll performance within a `UITableView` will be horrendous, and you should not use this!  I only provide this answer for technical accuracy and comprehensiveness.

As it looks like you copied this code from somewhere, there are many open source categories that will asynchronously load images from a url.

One such open source project is SDWebImage.  https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage   It's a widely used project that easily allows you to **asynchronously** load a `UIImage` from a url.

Comment: Do not do this. Loading an URL like this will block the main thread while the network is being accessed. Your app will be unresponsive during that time.

Comment: Sure. Your answer wasn't as complete when I commented :-) You've edited it since.

Answer (score 0):

`-setImageWithURL:` is not an `UIImage` method. You want to fetch the image data first, using `NSURLRequest`, `NSURLSession`, etc. ([documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165i)). Then allocate an UIImage and use the `initWithData:` constructor. Then use the image view's `setImage:` method to set it.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 [cell.avatarImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.innovaworks.com/wp-content/themes/innovaworks/images/home_person.png"]];
```

Or

```
cell.avatarImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.innovaworks.com/wp-content/themes/innovaworks/images/home_person.png"]]];
```

Comment: duplicate of my answer.

Comment: @arbi mahdi..  remove ".image" from your code.. it will work.. else your code is correct.. this is coz UIImage doesn't have a setImageWithURL:method. :)

Comment: Dear Nikita, you can't give answers as try this or this or this or this, if anyone doesn't work check for other's answer. Still not able to find then Google ... lol