# How to show a image from a url and load it into a UIImageView

Tags: ios, xcode, image, uiimageview

I need to load a image from a URL into a UIImageView. Each time the URL would be different because i am JSON parsing a website. I am able to get the URL. However when i run the app, there is no image in the UIImageView.

This is my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    if ([eventNameDesc containsString:@"src="]) {
        eventNameDesc = @"";
    }
    else {
        eventDescription.text = eventNameDesc;
    }
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(shareButtonPressed)];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(IBAction)shareButtonPressed {
    NSString *shareText = eventNameDesc;
    NSArray *itemsToShare = @[shareText];
    UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:itemsToShare applicationActivities:nil];
    activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[];
    [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)loadImage {
    NSData* imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.imageURL]];
    UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(displayImage:) withObject:image waitUntilDone:NO];
}

- (void)displayImage:(UIImage *)image {
    [self.ImageView setImage:image]; //UIImageView
}

@end
```

What is wrong with my code? Somebody please help.

Comment: Do you have a valid image URL? Could you open it in browser and ensure that it works?

Comment: It is a valid URL. I tried to open it an edit shows the image

Comment: Could you share sample URL?

Comment: where you call `loadImage`?

Comment: http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-K7vl-ShXrNc/VQU-D0NTFgI/AAAAAAAAAOg/aBIUOwF2nEQ/s1600/contact.png
This is a sample URL

Comment: I did not call  `loadImage`

Comment: I was able to check and your code works fine. But if you not calling `loadImage` that means that you actually not retrieving image at all

Comment: Just call your `-loadImage` somewhere. For example in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: i don't understand how to call `-loadImage`. Sorry i am just a beginner.

Comment: For some reason it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a `UIImage` object using the code provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2782491/1891327)

After that you can add your `UIImage` object to any `UIImageView` object. 
This is the code that works for me.

```
UIImage *anImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-K7vl-ShXrNc/VQU-D0NTFgI/AAAAAAAAAOg/aBIUOwF2nEQ/s1600/contact.png"]]];
UIImageView *temp = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:anImage];
[self.view addSubview:temp];
```

Here is a [screenshot.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/21750763/iOS%20Simulator%20Screen%20Shot%2018-Mar-2015%207.09.13%20pm.png)

Comment: @DineshSekar Please see the code that I am using on top and see the screenshot where its working for me.

Comment: i copied your code and pasted it into my `viewDidLoad`. But it didn't work for me.

Comment: It works for me if i do it in a new project. However when i do it in my original project it doesn't work

Comment: @DineshSekar where does your self.Imageview come from? Is it initialized?

Comment: i think that the `UIImageView` that your code creates is being blocked by my navigation controller. Is to possible for me to place it somewhere else programmatically.

Comment: it comes from my .h file

Comment: @DineshSekar in your displayImage function create new UIImageView and init it with the UIImage object passed. and add it. That worked for me. //    UIImageView *asdf = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
//    [self.view addSubview:asdf];

Comment: @DineshSekar can you show me the code where you are creating new uiimageView.

Comment: @DineshSekar start with creating your NSData, UIImage and UIImageView in your viewDidLoad. See if it works there. Then shift the entire code on to the selector and onwards and figure out where it stops working.

Comment: `- (void)displayImage:(UIImage *)image {
    UIImage *anImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-K7vl-ShXrNc/VQU-D0NTFgI/AAAAAAAAAOg/aBIUOwF2nEQ/s1600/contact.png"]]];
    UIImageView *temp = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:anImage];
    [self.view addSubview:temp];
}`

This is my code

Comment: i don't think that it stops working. I think that it cannot be seen because when i try it without the navigation bar it works.

Comment: Awesome.. I am so glad :D 
How did it work by the way?

Comment: I created my own `UIImageView` and then added this code into the `viewDidLoad` `UIImage *anImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.imageURL]]];
    imageView.image = anImage;`